# Windows: conda recognized, python is not

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

When I try to use python from either command prompt or windows powershell, I get the error that "Python was not found". This started happening after I recently reinstalled Anaconda, which is how I install and manage python and related packages.

What's odd is that "conda --version" works fine in command prompt. Also, "python --version" works fine in Anaconda prompt. But, I have added the output of "where python" in the Anaconda prompt to the user variable "Path" under environment variables, along with the outputs of "where conda". I'll note that this is within my user directory, which contains a space in the name, but the same is true for the conda path definition and that seems to work just fine.

Windows 10 Enterprise, conda 4.10.3, python 3.9.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may have already answered my own question, though I don't fully understand why the fix was needed.

I tried "conda activate base" in powershell and it failed and told me to run "conda init ", which I did and then restarted powershell. It now opens in the base environment and things seem to work fine now. I don't remember having to do this before, I think because an anaconda update (applied when I reinstalled) made using an environment required whereas it wasn't before. Not sure that's the right explanation so I'll leave this up for a bit, but this did seem to fix my issue.